# CGRectIntersection is not working after CGAffineTransformRotate

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rotation, uipangesturerecognizer

First of all I have checked almost every places over the internet but I didn't get any solution about this topic.

In my cases I have multiple UIView objects inside a superview or you can say a canvas where I am drawing this views.

1. All this views are attached with pan gesture so they can be moved inside anywhere of their superview.
2. Some of this views can be rotated using either rotation gesture or CGAffineTransformRotate.

   3. Whenever any of the view will be outside of the main view then it will be deleted.

Now following are my code.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainView: UIView!

  var newViewToAdd = UIView()
  newViewToAdd.layer.masksToBounds = true
  var transForm = CGAffineTransformIdentity
  transForm = CGAffineTransformScale(transForm, 0.8, 1)
  transForm = CGAffineTransformRotate(transForm, CGFloat(M_PI_4)) //Making the transformation
  newViewToAdd.layer.shouldRasterize = true //Making the view edges smooth after applying transforamtion
  newViewToAdd.transform = transForm
  self.mainView.addSubview(newViewToAdd) //Adding the view to the main view.
```

Now in case the gesture recognizer its inside the custom UIView Class -

```
var lastLocation: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
    lastLocation = self.center //Getting the last center point of the view on first touch.
  }

  func detectPan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.superview!) //Making the translation
    self.center = CGPointMake(lastLocation.x + translation.x, lastLocation.y + translation.y) //Updating the center point.
    switch(recognizer.state){
    case .Began:
             break
    case .Changed:
        //MARK: - Checking The view is outside of the Superview or not
        if (!CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectIntersection(self.superview!.bounds, self.frame), self.frame)) //if its true then view background color will be changed else background will be replaced.
        {
            self.backgroundColor = outsideTheViewColor
            var imageViewBin : UIImageView
            imageViewBin  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 25));
            imageViewBin.image = UIImage(named:"GarbageBin")
            imageViewBin.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/2)
            addSubview(imageViewBin)

        }else{
            for subViews in self.subviews{
                if subViews.isKindOfClass(UIImageView){
                    subViews.removeFromSuperview()
                }
                self.backgroundColor = deSelectedColorForTable
            }
        }
    case .Ended:
        if (!CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectIntersection(self.superview!.bounds, self.frame), self.frame)) //If its true then the view will be deleted.
        {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }

    default: break
    }
}
```

The main problem is if the view is not rotated or transformed then all the "CGRectIntersection" inside the .Changed/.Ended case is working fine as expected but if the view is rotated or transformed then "CGRectIntersection" always becoming true even the view is inside the "mainView" and its removing from the mainview/superview.

Please help about my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame of the view gets updated after applying transform. Following code ensures that it is inside the its superviews bounds.

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(self.superview!.bounds, self.frame))
{
    //view is inside of the Superview
}
else
{
    //view is outside of the Superview
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your time. Can you please tell me more about your solution and what about mine..???

        if (!CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectIntersection(self.superview!.bounds, self.frame), self.frame))

What is the actual problem with this...??

Comment: Your code also looks proper to me. I did a POC it works perfectly for me. Possible reason might be you mainview frame out of screen. Please check mainview's frame and constraints.

Comment: Okay...I will check that also..but the thing is if the mainview's frame is out of screen then how my code works, when I am not rotating any view inside of the main view..By the way thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: In my last comment i meant to say, possible reason might be you mainview frame is not proper .Try by setting mainView.clipsToBounds = true.

Comment: Thanks for the tip...I will let you if this works...Thank you.

Comment: WOW...+1 just for you mate. I did a lot of research, made so many algorithms but nothing helped me..Only your suggestion and guide did the trick...thank you very much.